# Same html/css code different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mysql

I'm developing a website integrated with a data base. And in one of the pages I present many tables, with different information. The tables have, or are supposed to have, functionalities such as order by, seach, rows per page, etc. and all are indeed working.

Now imagine that I make two tables with the exactly the same code. What is happening is that the first one has those funcionalities that I enumerated before, but the second one won't have. The table will be presented with the right information but without the functionalities. I'm not understanding why, since the code is exactly the same. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<div class="content-box-large">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title"><b>Eventos</b></div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Local</th>
                            <th>Data de Início</th>
                            <th>Data de Fim</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php               
                        $SQL_Eventos                = "select * from Eventos";
                        $resultado_Eventos          = mysqli_query($ligacao,$SQL_Eventos);

                        if($resultado_Eventos)
                        {
                            while($tuplo = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_Eventos))
                            {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                    <?php
                            $Ev_Nome                = $tuplo["Nome"];
                            $Ev_Tipo                = $tuplo["Tipo"];
                            $Ev_DataInicio          = $tuplo["DataInicio"];
                            $Ev_DataFim             = $tuplo["DataFim"];
                            $Ev_Local               = $tuplo["Sitio"];
                    ?>
                            <th><?php echo $Ev_Nome ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $Ev_Tipo ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $Ev_Local ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $Ev_DataInicio ?></th>
                            <th><?php echo $Ev_DataFim ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
$.extend( true, $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
    "sDom":
        "<'row'<'col-xs-6'l><'col-xs-6'f>r>"+
        "t"+
        "<'row'<'col-xs-6'i><'col-xs-6'p>>",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
    }
} );


/* Default class modification */
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    "sWrapper": "dataTables_wrapper form-inline",
    "sFilterInput": "form-control input-sm",
    "sLengthSelect": "form-control input-sm"
} );

// In 1.10 we use the pagination renderers to draw the Bootstrap paging,
// rather than  custom plug-in
if ( $.fn.dataTable.Api ) {
    $.fn.dataTable.defaults.renderer = 'bootstrap';
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.renderer.pageButton.bootstrap = function ( settings, 
host, idx, buttons, page, pages ) {
        var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
        var classes = settings.oClasses;
        var lang = settings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
        var btnDisplay, btnClass;

        var attach = function( container, buttons ) {
            var i, ien, node, button;
            var clickHandler = function ( e ) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if ( e.data.action !== 'ellipsis' ) {
                    api.page( e.data.action ).draw( false );
                }
            };

            for ( i=0, ien=buttons.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                button = buttons[i];

                if ( $.isArray( button ) ) {
                    attach( container, button );
                }
                else {
                    btnDisplay = '';
                    btnClass = '';

                    switch ( button ) {
                        case 'ellipsis':
                            btnDisplay = '&hellip;';
                            btnClass = 'disabled';
                            break;

                        case 'first':
                            btnDisplay = lang.sFirst;
                            btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                                '' : ' disabled');
                            break;

                        case 'previous':
                            btnDisplay = lang.sPrevious;
                            btnClass = button + (page > 0 ?
                                '' : ' disabled');
                            break;

                        case 'next':
                            btnDisplay = lang.sNext;
                            btnClass = button + (page < pages-1 ?
                                '' : ' disabled');
                            break;

                        case 'last':
                            btnDisplay = lang.sLast;
                            btnClass = button + (page < pages-1 ?
                                '' : ' disabled');
                            break;

                        default:
                            btnDisplay = button + 1;
                            btnClass = page === button ?
                                'active' : '';
                            break;
                    }

                    if ( btnDisplay ) {
                        node = $('<li>', {
                                'class': classes.sPageButton+' '+btnClass,
                                'aria-controls': settings.sTableId,
                                'tabindex': settings.iTabIndex,
                                'id': idx === 0 && typeof button === 'string' ?
                                    settings.sTableId +'_'+ button :
                                    null
                            } )
                            .append( $('<a>', {
                                'href': '#'
                                } )
                                .html( btnDisplay )
                            )
                            .appendTo( container );

                        settings.oApi._fnBindAction(
                            node, {action: button}, clickHandler
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        attach(
            $(host).empty().html('<ul class="pagination"/>').children('ul'),
            buttons
        );
    }
}
else {
    // Integration for 1.9-
    $.fn.dataTable.defaults.sPaginationType = 'bootstrap';

    /* API method to get paging information */
    $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
    {
        return {
            "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
            "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
            "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
            "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
            "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
            "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / 
oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
            "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
                0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / 
oSettings._iDisplayLength )
        };
     };

    /* Bootstrap style pagination control */
    $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oPagination, {
        "bootstrap": {
            "fnInit": function( oSettings, nPaging, fnDraw ) {
                var oLang = oSettings.oLanguage.oPaginate;
                var fnClickHandler = function ( e ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if ( oSettings.oApi._fnPageChange(oSettings, e.data.action) ) {
                        fnDraw( oSettings );
                    }
                };

                $(nPaging).append(
                    '<ul class="pagination">'+
                        '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">&larr; 
'+oLang.sPrevious+'</a></li>'+
                        '<li class="next disabled"><a href="#">'+oLang.sNext+' &rarr; </a></li>'+
                    '</ul>'
                );
                var els = $('a', nPaging);
                $(els[0]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "previous" }, fnClickHandler );
                $(els[1]).bind( 'click.DT', { action: "next" }, fnClickHandler );
            },

            "fnUpdate": function ( oSettings, fnDraw ) {
                var iListLength = 5;
                var oPaging = oSettings.oInstance.fnPagingInfo();
                var an = oSettings.aanFeatures.p;
                var i, ien, j, sClass, iStart, iEnd, iHalf=Math.floor(iListLength/2);

                if ( oPaging.iTotalPages < iListLength) {
                    iStart = 1;
                    iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                }
                else if ( oPaging.iPage <= iHalf ) {
                    iStart = 1;
                    iEnd = iListLength;
                } else if ( oPaging.iPage >= (oPaging.iTotalPages-iHalf) ) {
                    iStart = oPaging.iTotalPages - iListLength + 1;
                    iEnd = oPaging.iTotalPages;
                } else {
                    iStart = oPaging.iPage - iHalf + 1;
                    iEnd = iStart + iListLength - 1;
                }

                for ( i=0, ien=an.length ; i<ien ; i++ ) {
                    // Remove the middle elements
                    $('li:gt(0)', an[i]).filter(':not(:last)').remove();

                    // Add the new list items and their event handlers
                    for ( j=iStart ; j<=iEnd ; j++ ) {
                        sClass = (j==oPaging.iPage+1) ? 'class="active"' : '';
                        $('<li '+sClass+'><a href="#">'+j+'</a></li>')
                            .insertBefore( $('li:last', an[i])[0] )
                            .bind('click', function (e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                oSettings._iDisplayStart = (parseInt($('a', this).text(),10)-1) * oPaging.iLength;
                                fnDraw( oSettings );
                            } );
                    }

                    // Add / remove disabled classes from the static elements
                    if ( oPaging.iPage === 0 ) {
                        $('li:first', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('li:first', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                    }

                    if ( oPaging.iPage === oPaging.iTotalPages-1 || oPaging.iTotalPages === 0 ) {
                        $('li:last', an[i]).addClass('disabled');
                    } else {
                        $('li:last', an[i]).removeClass('disabled');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } );
}


/*
 * TableTools Bootstrap compatibility
 * Required TableTools 2.1+
 */
if ( $.fn.DataTable.TableTools ) {
    // Set the classes that TableTools uses to something suitable for Bootstrap
    $.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.classes, {
        "container": "DTTT btn-group",
        "buttons": {
            "normal": "btn btn-default",
            "disabled": "disabled"
        },
        "collection": {
            "container": "DTTT_dropdown dropdown-menu",
            "buttons": {
                "normal": "",
                "disabled": "disabled"
            }
        },
        "print": {
            "info": "DTTT_print_info modal"
        },
        "select": {
            "row": "active"
        }
    } );

    // Have the collection use a bootstrap compatible dropdown
    $.extend( true, $.fn.DataTable.TableTools.DEFAULTS.oTags, {
        "collection": {
            "container": "ul",
            "button": "li",
            "liner": "a"
        }
    } );
}
```

**EDIT**

So i found that the problem is the id's. It doesn't matter if i have 1 or 2 or 3 tables, the functionalities will only work if i have my id = "example", but since i can't have two tables with the same id, how can i overcome this?

Comment: Where is JavaScrpt (or jQuery) in your code?

Comment: The functionality you’re asking about is likely provided by javascript code so, we’ll need to see that.

Comment: Its on this link: https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js . On my file i do: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: You are missing some JS code here. Showing us JQuery does not help. JQuery may be doing the sorting actions for you, but you have to call the function first. We need to see that

Comment: This is the library, not your JS code... How are you using the jQuery library on your code? can you setup any https://jsfiddle.net to make easier for us?

Comment: Don't actually use any jQuery. I literally just do that code of the table, some menus, and call some libraries. This libraries:

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="vendors/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script src="vendors/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tables.js"></script>

Comment: Already edited the post with JS code.
@mingos what is wrong with the php code? This is how i am learning on university ahah

Comment: @cesarPR Mixing presentation (HTML) with business logic (database interaction) is considered very bad practice. I'm afraid the comments are not the best place to go into any more detail.

Comment: Do both your tables have the same id? ids have to be unique. this might not be the problem - but it kinda sounds like it could be this.

Comment: I thought of that and tried with different id's, and the results are the same. Only the first one has the functionalities

Comment: This is so weird. If i use google chrome dev tools, to see each element, on the first table i can see each html element of the funcionalities. On the second table those don't exist

Comment: Please check my last uptate guys